# Variable amount of slices : Pie Chart concept

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is my image sketch:

[image: pie chart]

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bqah9jex/) to work on:

```
 <div id="a"></div>
```

the goal is to divide this circle into variable amount of slices.

for instance if i want 10 slices.. i can just change something to "10"
and it will show me this ring that has been divided into 10 pieces.

or '20' or '50' or '100'.

in other words some way to avoid having to deal with each individual line.

being able to rotate would be a plus.

alternatively.. i also would like the version of this.. within which only the border is divided into X slices.

either would work fine for me.

Comment: Maybe this link will get you started http://codepen.io/AtomicNoggin/pen/fEish

Comment: That one goes on and on. it works with each slice individually. can consume too much time.

Comment: What have you tried? Fiddle's are not supposed to serve as sources for the code required to answer your question.

Comment: StackOverflow is not really the place to ask people to do **all** the work for you. You should at least provide an attempt which we can help you improve.

Comment: code occupies too much space .

Comment: i asked if there was a wild card method to divide a circle into slices. that was the question. have not asked anyone to do all my work for me.

Comment: @user3970891 there is no limit to the length of a question. Have you even tried to draw an angled line? anything aside from making a circle?

Comment: I do not have such css skills. i did it in the image sketch included in this question.

Comment: oh i see.. i just need lines ? I thought maybe there was a feature in css it could go in the center of any circle and just expand in all directions.

Comment: I'm looking into this. I don't think it is too difficult.

Comment: @user3970891 take a look at my answer. should take care of it for you.

Comment: amazing stuff. i tried it with 100,800,1000. almost as if things are getting connected with the cosmos.

Comment: @user3970891 yeah! I was surprised by that, but it's a really cool effect. You could probably do some fancy stuff with it.

Comment: @user3970891 added a spin animation on hover in case you are curious : http://jsfiddle.net/bqah9jex/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So came up with a nice little script for you. Fairly straight forward, and should work on any size circle you throw at it.

Used minimalist HTML and took care of the rest using jQuery:

### HTML

```
<div id="a" data-lines="8"></div>
```

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var numLines = parseInt($('#a').data('lines'));
    var theta = 180/(numLines/2);
    var center = $('#a').innerWidth()/2 - 1; /*-1 to account for the line width*/
    var currAngle = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < numLines/2; i++){
        $('<div class="lines" style="' + setAngle(currAngle) +' top: ' + center + 'px;"></div>').appendTo('#a');
        currAngle += theta;
    }
});

function setAngle(theta) {
    return '-ms-transform: rotate('+ theta +'deg); -webkit-transform: rotate('+ theta +'deg); transform: rotate('+ theta +'deg);';
}
```

### [Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bqah9jex/3/)

--Just a side note... the more lines you add the cooler it looks

Also, just playing around and added a spin animation on hover... http://jsfiddle.net/bqah9jex/4/

Answer (score 1):

Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/bqah9jex/10/ .. extra compact Javascript, HTML and CSS code to represent Pie Chart.

### HTML

```
<div id="a"></div>
```

### CSS

```
#a{width:25em;height:25em;border:1em red solid;text-align:center;
   border-radius:50%;background:#fff;position:relative
}
.l{width:100%;border:1px solid black;position:absolute}
```

### Javascript

```
$(function () {
    for (var a = 0, c = 200; c--;) {
        var b = "transform: rotate(" + a + "deg)";
        $('<div class="l" style="'+ ("-ms-"+ b + ";
           -webkit-"+ b + ";" + b + ";") + 'top: 50%;"></div>').appendTo("#a");
        a += 194; // number of lines
    }
});
```

### Demo result

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFQZ6.png